# Why my 9 patch not working properly?

Tags: android, nine-patch

i have the a 9 patch image with a magnifying glass icon on the right side for my search box,

the problem is, the image doesn't fit well while i put it as background for my edittext.
(i can't upload the screenshoot yet)

the magnifying glass icon didn't work as expected, the icon got shrunk there. can someone help me fix this?

here my XML code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ListFoodActivity"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/bcground"
android:src="@drawable/bcground" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Food"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:background="@drawable/search"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

here the 9 patch image :

[image]

and the image of the emulator :

[image]

sorry for the bad english :(

Comment: please put your 9 patch image here.i will check its created properly or not?

Comment: i don't know how to upload images now, because stackoverflow said i need 10 reputation before i can uploading any images here

here : http://i.imgur.com/JHTwwda.png

the image should be like this if it working

http://i.imgur.com/S9AKX7R.png

Comment: please upload your image in http://postimage.org/

Comment: please upload your image without create ninepatch.

Comment: here the original image (before 9 patch) : http://s8.postimg.org/9i5gl22ph/search.png

Comment: please use this image.....http://s21.postimg.org/lxlbahotj/search_9.png
but you must fixed this image height..then this image working fine..otherwise if you don't fixed height of this image,then base on your different device image will be stregth on height.

Comment: hey.rizki have you solved your issue or not?

Comment: its better, but still doesnt perfect.. can you teach me how to make that image?

here the result : http://postimg.org/image/tmorfhall/

Comment: sorry i forget 1 thing...this search is image can not be converted in 9patch.because in this image one serach image is there.so this image will be stretch when whole image stretch in nine patch image.so when only simple image can be converted in 9patch..icon images can't be converted.if you any doubt then tell me

Comment: i found out what you mean yesterday, and i already change the design... thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the 9 patch itself: it's **malformed**.
The black line on the **left side** is simply WRONG (it "touches" the lens).
It should be a single pixel near the lower part, so that its prolongation doesn't touch the lens.

This is it

[image]

Note that the lens will be **up-right aligned**.
If you want it **centered**, you have to add another black pixel near the upper left border (but you have to replace some pixels near the upper lens frame, too).

Also not thet you don't need the horizontal part being that wide, you can make it **much narrower**, to save on the final patch size.

Comment: i hardly understand this, can you help me with better ilustration?

i made it look like this, and its not working like you said

http://postimg.org/image/nsvilzrdf/

Comment: See my edited answer. I gave you the finished YourFile.9.png (you must save it as .9.png)

Comment: I found out what you mean, thanks a lot... 

it really help me out :D

Comment: OK, fine.  Now a tip: use the drawpatch tool to verify your 9 patches are well done and edit them accordigly (maybe you still have to retouch them with an image editor though).

Answer (score -1):

After using 9patch to create a photo, you can a image file which it's file extension is XX.9.png.
For example, search.9.png in drawable folder and you should use "android:background=@drawable/search" in xml.

Comment: i already do that, the problem is, the image doesnt appear properly in emulator, please check the post again, i added the screenshoot just now